# C++ cin >> double not in scientific

Tags: c++, double, std, cin

```
std::stringstream is ( "a12.34e" );
double d;
char c;
is >> c >> d;
// d = 0
```

How do I make it to read the double as `std::fixed` and not as `std::scientific` (12.34e+001)?

Comment: By not using `istream::operator>>`, which always uses `std::num_get`, which converts as-if `sscanf` was used with the `%g` specifier.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the e after the number yields 12.34 as output.

As the first comment to your question indicates, the following works as well:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    double d;
    char c;
    sscanf("a12.34e", "%c%lf", &c, &d);
    printf("%c %lf\n", c, d); 
    return 0;
}
```

output: a 12.340000

Answer (score -3):

```
std::stringstream is ( "a12.34e" );
double d;
char c;
is >> c >>std::fixed >> d;
```